# Showing the user name in navigation bar using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, web, navigation, dropdown

I want to show the username or the user type(student/faculty/admin) in the navigation bar beside 'Home','Contact','About' links.
This button or link will have a drop down menu, which further links out to the function that user is permitted.
Like:
Student
-Upload Image
-Update Information
-Share Views
-Check Attendance

whereas the admin panel will be like:
Admin
-Fill Attendance
-Update Data of student
-New Student

like this.
I am using Php as front end and MySQL in back end, the doing this on XAMPP.

Comment: PHP is not front end.

Comment: this question should not even exist.

Comment: please post your code

Answer (score 1):

First of all PHP is not front end, it is a server side scripting language. Second, if you want to show the name of the user of the pages you can save his username in a session variable and display it wherever you want to. 
For the you have to start session using 
`session_start` and save the name in a session variable. You can refer it here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Answer (score 0):

- You're looking at MySQL to store that student/faculty/admin information as well as associated permissions.
- You're looking at PHP to grab that database information server-side and HTML display it next to your menu.
- You're looking at javascript/css to provide the styling of that HTML and the dynamic view functionality (including the front-end drop-down menu) that you described.

I'm not entirely sure from your question which aspect of this you're having trouble with, but hopefully this helps point you in the right direction!